# How to find multiple classes within a variable? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My unsecesfull on doing so is following:

```
    var myForm = $("#my-form");

    var myElements = myForm.find(".first-class .second-class");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to select elements that have both classes? Or elements that have either class?

Comment: @4castle Yes, I am. The answer below fits my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are inside the `my-form` element, you could find them separated by comma `,`. For sample:

```
var myElements = myForm.find(".first-class, .second-class");
```

Comment: Welcome. I'm not a native english speaker either, always happy to get corrected grammar... :-)